# What is "can_delete_extra" for in Django Admin?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-admin

I have `Person` model and `Email` model which has the foreign key of `Person` model as shown below:

```py
# "models.py"

class Person(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=20)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class Email(models.Model):
    person = models.ForeignKey(Person, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    email = models.EmailField()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.email
```

Then, I set [can_delete_extra = True](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/topics/forms/formsets/#can-delete-extra) to `Email` inline as shown below:

```py
# "admin.py"

class EmailInline(admin.TabularInline):
    model = Email
    can_delete_extra = True # Here

@admin.register(Person)
class PersonAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    inlines = (EmailInline,)
```

Or, I set `can_delete_extra = False` to `Email` inline as shown below:

```py
# "admin.py"

class EmailInline(admin.TabularInline):
    model = Email
    can_delete_extra = False # Here

@admin.register(Person)
class PersonAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    inlines = (EmailInline,)
```

But, nothing happens to `DELETE?` check boxes on `change` page as shown below:

[image]

I know if setting [can_delete = False](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/topics/forms/formsets/#can-delete) to `Email` inline as shown below:

```py
# "admin.py"

class EmailInline(admin.TabularInline):
    model = Email
    can_delete = False # Here

@admin.register(Person)
class PersonAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    inlines = (EmailInline,)
```

Then, I can hide `DELETE?` check boxes on `change` page as shown below:

[image]

So, what is `can_delete_extra` for in Django?

Answer (score 0):

Per the Django docs:

**can_delete_extra**

`BaseFormSet.can_delete_extra`

Default: `True`

While setting `can_delete=True`, specifying `can_delete_extra=False` will remove the option to delete extra forms.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/topics/forms/formsets/#can-delete-extra